# How do I return these using only one method?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, methods, return

```
public class newClass {


public static void main(String[] args)

{
    int nullValue=0;
    int nullValue2=1;
    int nullValue3=0;
    int nullValue4=0;
    int [] sourceArray = {4,5,6,7};
    int [] targetArray = new int [4];


    for (int i=0; i<sourceArray.length; i++)
    {
        nullValue+=sourceArray[i];
    }
    targetArray[0]=nullValue;

    // I added all sourceArray elements together and passed it to targetArray[0]


    for (int i=0; i<sourceArray.length; i++)
    {
        nullValue2*=sourceArray[i];
    }
    targetArray[1]=nullValue2;

    // I multiplied all sourceArray elements together and assigned the result to targetArray[1]


    for (int i=0; i<sourceArray.length; i++)
    {
        nullValue3 += getResult(sourceArray[i]);
    }
    targetArray[2]=nullValue3;

    // I tried to add all odd numbers in sourceArray together and assign it to targetArray[2]


    for (int i=0; i<sourceArray.length; i++)
    {
        nullValue4 += getResult(sourceArray[i]);    
    }
    targetArray[3]=nullValue4;


    // Same as previous except I need to do that with even numbers.

}



public static int getResult (int x)
{


    if (x%2 == 0)
    {
        return x;
    }

    else
    {
        return 0;
    }


}



}
```

You can read my comments above. I realize I can create another method for the last part but I am supposed to use only one method to return odds and evens. I tried almost anything. I can't think of any other ways anymore. Obviously I can't return x in both cases(Yeah I was too desperate to try that). 
    Straight to the point. I need one method to return x if it's odd or if it's even(We can say it's impossible by the look of that sentence already). I guess that's impossible to do with only one method. I'm not good at java yet so I'm not sure. Maybe there are other ways to do that with only one method which may be so easy. I worked on it for like 6 hours so I'm asking you guys. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _return x if it's odd or if it's even_? I read that as _I want to return x_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method to return a boolean if the number is even like so

```
  public static boolean isEven(int x)
  {
      return (x%2 == 0)
  }
```

Then in your loop for evens

```
for (int i=0; i<sourceArray.length; i++)
{
    if(isEven(x))
         nullValue3 += sourceArray[i];
}
```

For odds just change to `if(!isEven(x))`

---

But this is probably deviating from the requirements as  you probably want a method that returns an int and you could just put the condition directly in the loop and not need a method

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want is to be able to tell the `getResult` function whether to give you only odd numbers or only even numbers. Without getting complicated, this is what I would do:

```
public static int getResult(int x, boolean evens) {
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
        return evens ? x : 0; // shorthand for: if(evens) {return x;} else {return 0;}
    } else {
        return evens ? 0 : x;
    }
}
```

Simply speaking, I pass a flag value (`evens`) to the `getResult` function. This flag tells me whether to filter for even numbers or for odd numbers.

I test whether `x` is even (`x % 2 == 0`). If it is, I return it if I'm looking for evens, and I return `0` if I'm looking for odds. If `x` wasn't even, then I do the opposite.

---

It would be a little cleaner to write a pair of helper functions, which you could then call from your `getResult` function.

```
private static int getIfEven(x) {
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
        return x;
    }
    return 0;
}

private static int getIfOdd(x) {
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return x;
}

public static int getResult(int x, boolean evens) {
    // shorthand for:
    // if (evens) {
    //     return getIfEven(x);
    // } else {
    //     return getIfOdd(x);
    // }
    return evens ? getIfEven(x) : getIfOdd(x);
}
```

---

Depending on how much you're allowed to deviate from the current setup (I assume this is homework), you could also just write an `isEven(int x)` function and call that at each step through the loop, only adding the number if it is/isn't even.

Comment: Why not `if(x % 2 == 0 && evens)` is that's the case?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Because I'm being pedantic for the sake of being clear about what I'm doing :-) Clearly there are shorter ways to write the code, but I don't want to add to the confusion if I can help it.